# array data manipulation and retrieval

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an multi-dimensinal array:

I have flattened it one level with `$array= call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);`

Now when I attempt to access the dating using

```
foreach($array as $field)
{
   echo $field['Section_title'];      // echo id 

}
```

I get the results through all nested arrays but I just want to reference  each individual one. Instead of getting #1, I want to get #2. Can someone educate me on how to properly read through and reference nested arrays?

> 1.{Conditions and Symptoms,Emergency Contacts,etc}
>
> 2.{Conditions and Symptoms}

### The array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Section_title] => Conditions and Symptoms
                    [section_subtitle] => Does the patient have 
                    [additional_info] => 
                    [section_disclaimer] => 
                    [disclaimer_title] => 
                    [section_makercol] => 
                    [field_title_1] => Tuberculosis
                    [field_title_2] => Chronic cough
                    [field_title_3] => Asthma
                    [field_title_4] => Diabetes

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Section_title] => Emergency Contacts
                    [section_subtitle] => 
                    [additional_info] => 
                    [section_disclaimer] => 
                    [disclaimer_title] => 
                    [section_makercol] => 
                    [field_title_1] => Name
                    [field_title_2] => Phone #
                    [field_title_3] => Address
                    [field_title_4] => City

                )

            [2] => Array
               ( 

               )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through key value:

```
foreach($array as $field)
{
   foreach ($field as $key => $value){
       echo $field[$key]; //
   }
}
```

Comment: problem with this is it still loops through all the arrays how do i constrain it to just the first nested array?

Comment: you can remove the first loop then and just make the second loop `$array[0] as $key => $value`